# sql developer issue in visualizing date

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

since few weeks I started working on SQL developer.

I noticed an important issue that I do not know how to solve. This is related to the way my SQL developer visualizes the date.

First of all, here are my settings:
[image]

and here is my problem:

```
select to_date('01-01-0001', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual;
```

#### Instead of correctly visualizin 01-01-2001, it visualizes 03-JAN-0001

[image]

```
select select to_date('01-01-2001', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual;
```

It is interesting to observe that the issue of the day disappear when we change year.

[image]

Comment: I can't get the point: your settings say to use the format DD-MON-RRRR and this is what I see in the result; what did you expect instead?

Comment: The point is that instead of visualizing 1st january, it visualized 3rd january

Comment: it's a bug @Seymour see my answer below, are you the same one to report this on the forums this week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this -

[image]

- defines for your session how to display dates and timestamps.

Example:

[image]

If you were querying a date w/o supplying a date format, then it adopts said settings.

But if you query a string, and ask Oracle to treat it as a date

```
select to_date('1-1-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual;
```

The DD-MM-YYYY tells Oracle how to interpret your string as a date.

And then the output is shown using the format defined for NLS

[image]

Now, for your scenario, the year '1' - there is a bug in SQL Developer 18.1 that is causing the date to come back as 3 vs 1.

```
Bug 28093149 - DATE IS RETURNED INCORRECTLY FOR 01/01/0001 - COMES BACK AS 03/01/0001
```

Comment: But why none of my friend has this bug?

Comment: @Seymour b/c they're not on 18.1? I don't know what your friends have, i can only tell you what i know based on what you told me and what i know about the Bug